# Used Disk Cleanup, now my Win7 won't boot

Tags: windows-7, boot, disk-cleanup

I have a Windows7 machine (I know it's old, it's running some legacy stuff). It was running out of disk space, so I used its Disk Cleanup tool to clean up some old files. As a result, it stopped letting me log on, and when I restarted it, it now won't boot, saying MissingOsLoader. 1) how do I get back to a bootable system, and 2) is Disk Cleanup not safe to use?!

Comment: I'm assuming you mean the built in [Disk Cleanup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cqNAB.png) rather than some other tool by the same name. I've used it many times and never had any issues and there's nothing it should do that would destroy a disk unless it was already near failure. What kind of disk is it? If it is an SSD it might have been near failure already.

Comment: it was a normal HDD (not an SSD) and never indicated any issues yet.

Answer (score 2):

Disk Cleanup is usually very safe to use, so it's possible that some
new hardware error has occurred (especially with an old disk).

To recover, you will need a Windows 7 boot media of the same
service pack level as is currently installed, or a
[System Repair Disc](https://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/2083-system-repair-disc-create.html)
if you have ever created one for your computer.

You need to boot from this media and do Startup Repair.

For detailed instructions with screenshots see
[How to Run a Startup Repair in Windows 7](https://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/681-startup-repair.html).

Comment: I do have a System 7 disk and I tried booting off it, getting to the System Recovery Options menu, and it said it "cannot repair this computer automatically", which is exactly what it was saying when I tried to boot off the internal hard drive. I'm not 100% sure it even was using the CD-R with Win7 on it - how do I confirm that? And to make a Windows7 repair disk, do I need to create it on another Windows7 machine? I don't have one, I only have a Windows10.

Comment: Use the boot menu (perhaps F12 on boot) to ensure you're booting from the USB. If it still happening, see [this advice](https://www.easeus.com/computer-instruction/startup-repair-cannot-repair-this-computer-automatically.html) for things to try (please report on what happened).